# How to list all the printers on the network?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, active-directory, printers

I am trying to list all the printers on the network (we have a very large, cross-ocean network) using VS2008 & c#.

I am looking to replicate the functionality of the Find Printers dialog box in Windows (which can be found by going to *Printers and Faxes*, clicking *Add a printer*, selecting *Network Printer*, then picking *Find a printer in the directory*.  From there you get this dialog box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all connected printer using GetPrintQueue function of PrintServer class in Sytem.Printing Namespace [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-print-queues-and-capabilities) is the good sample for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sample only deals with printers that are already connected to you.  I am looking for ALL printers on the network.

Comment: @AngryHacker: I'm a lil bit confuse here, so did Firoz answered your question? lol